# instantaneous transition rates in continuous-time Markov chain

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes

> Consider a set of n machines and a single repair facility to service
> these machines. Suppose that when machine i , i = 1,2, … n, fails, it
> requires an exponentially distributed amount of work with rate  to
> repair it. The repair facility divides its efforts equally among all
> failed machines in the sense that whenever there are k failed machines
> each one receives work at a rate of 1/k per unit time. If there are a
> total of r working machines, including machine i , then i fails at an
> instantaneous rate /r
>
> (a) Find the instantaneous transition rates
>
> The answer is as following,  [image]

Okay, I can understand that qS,S-i = µi / |S|. As far as I know, because the repair facility divides its efforts equally among all failed machines in the sense, we need to make µi divided by |S|.

But I cannot understand that qS,S+j = .

In my opinion, since the sentence-**"*i fails at an instantaneous rate /r*"** should imply that the rate at which process makes a transition from state S into state S+j is j/r, then qS,S+j should be
j/|$S^c$|.

Do I misunderstand something?